# assigning value for column based on whether or not text is present

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I have a data frame:

| Fruit | Color |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 'is green' |  |
| apple | 'big and Green' |  |
| apple | 'is red' |  |
| banana | 'yellow" |  |
| banana | 'is yellow' |  |
| banana | 'is small and yellow" |  |

I want to make a third column, called 'Green' , for all df['Fruit'] == 'apple' , which is binary and has a 1 for every value in the column 'Color' that contains the string 'green', and 0 for all those that dont, and for every value df['Fruit'] == 'Banana' the df['Green] == NA.

| Fruit | Color | Green |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 'is green' | 1 |
| apple | 'big and Green' | 1 |
| apple | 'is red' | 0 |
| banana | 'yellow" | NA |
| banana | 'is yellow' | NA |
| banana | 'is small and yellow" | NA |

I get an error when I run this:

df['Green'] = np.where((df['Fruit'] == 'apple') & (df['Color].str.lower().str.contains('green') == True), 1, 0)

Answer (score 2):

Create boolean masks then using boolean indexing with loc to assign values

```
m1 = df['Fruit'].eq('apple')
m2 = df['Color'].str.contains('(?i)green')
df.loc[m1, 'Green'] = (m1 & m2).astype('int')
```

---

```
    Fruit                  Color  Green
0   apple             'is green'    1.0
1   apple        'big and Green'    1.0
2   apple               'is red'    0.0
3  banana               'yellow"    NaN
4  banana            'is yellow'    NaN
5  banana  'is small and yellow"    NaN
```

Comment: You don't need `(m1 & m2)` since you're already using boolean indexing, `df.loc[m1, 'Green'] = m2.astype('int')` is enough ;)